# How do I find the equations of a hyperplane that has points inside a hypercube?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, 3d, plane-curves

I was trying to find $W,b$ such that $f(x) = W^T x + b = 0$ and that there exists more than one point in a hypercube $x \in [0,4]^D$ that satisfy $f(x) = 0$. In other words, I have a hypercube and I want to find a plane that goes through/cuts the hypercube but at the same time, those points that cut the plane must satisfy $f(x) = 0$. Ideally, we cut the hypercube not right at the edge, so that we actually cut through a whole piece of the hypercube.

To solve this and understand the problem in a simpler scenario I scaled it down to $D =  2$.

In this case when the hyperplane $f(x) = 0$ means that we have $W_1 x_1 + W_2 x_2 + b = 0$. In this case to find parameters $W,b$ to make that true I choose 3 points $a_1, a_2, a_3 \in [0,4]^2 $ such that $f(x) = 0$. Intuitively I choose 3 because I have three unknowns so I wanted to have enough equations and unknowns. I chose the points $a_1 = [2,2], a_2 = [4,0], a_3 = [0,4]$. With this I got the linear system:

$$ A[w,b] = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 2 & 2 & 1 \\ 4 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 4 & 1 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{ccc} W_1 \\ W_2 \\ b  \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right) $$

to my (no surprise) since the matrix A is invertible I found that the only solution that exists is $W = [0,0], b = 0$. Which from a linear algebra perspective with the system I set up makes sense. However, what does not make sense to me is the geometric intuition of the solution. What I was actually trying to attempt to do is choose plane that goes through the middle of the hypercube and that it also goes through two corners of the hypercube that I chose. This is what my picture looks like:

[image]

my intuition tells me that indeed there should be a **unique** plane that crosses those points (in this case a line but in reality we have a plane because we are choosing $f(x) = W^Tx + b$ to lie inside the hypercube) but the plane shouldn't the trivial silly equation $f(x) = 0x_1 + 0x_2 + 0$, which isn't even a plane and essentially is equal to zero everywhere. Where did I go wrong? Why wasn't I able to choose the hyperplane I intended to choose?

Comment: $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ **is** a plane.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla yea I know, but I can't figure out why it just doesn't pass through the hypercube I want. The vector $ [W_1, W_2, b] = 0$ is definitively not the plane I had in mind (as shown by my sketch).

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. On one hand, hyperplanes are too large to fit inside any hypercube, so the question in the title does not make a lot of sense, and then the first sentence of your question seems crytic to me!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I didn't realize the question was ambiguous (which I agree). I've improved it. Does it make more sense to you?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723294/how-to-determine-the-equation-of-the-hyperplane-that-contains-several-points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...the matrix A is invertible.." is false: $\det A = 0$ and you have nontrivial solutions, namely $W_1 = W_2 = -b/4\ne 0$.

Comment: Oh, your right, I had a typo in the command that I typed to matlab. Somehow I was unlucky enough that my typo made the matrix have det(A) = 16...